# Is ASUS X99 Deluxe motherboard compatible with a WD 2280 M.2 SSD?

Tags: hard-drive, motherboard, troubleshooting, m.2

I have a WD Blue™ 1TB M.2 2280 SSD, and an Asus X99 Deluxe motherboard. I noticed the M.2x4 slot on the motherboard and have read [the specs](https://dlcdnets.asus.com/pub/ASUS/mb/LGA2011/X99-DELUXE/E9504_X99-DELUXE_UG_WEB.pdf), so I called the manufacturer and they confirmed that it indeed does support M.2 drives, but it requires the special bracket to hold the drive in place, pictured here:

[image: Asus X99 Deluxe M.2x4 Vertical Mount].

They sent me the missing bracket that I either misplaced or never received, and I installed the aforementioned WD M.2. After a lot of time in the BIOS trying to recognize the device, I gave up. It fits into the slot perfectly, but it never detects. I looked into it and found out that this specific board only worked for a very few specific brands of M.2 drives [(in 2014)](https://linustechtips.com/topic/209142-asus-x99-deluxe-m2-ssd-not-detected/) but I have no reason to believe that ASUS wouldn't have updated their BIOS to support more at this point.

My question is this; will my WD 2280 work with the X99 Deluxe, and if so, what could I be missing?

Also in [this thread](https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/asus-x99-deluxe-u3-1-work-with-nvme.3398846/), they mention that I may need to disable other SATA ports to use this. I currently am using 2 other hard drives (500 gb SSD and 1TB HDD) in tandem. Would this mess with my configuration for a M.2?

Specs say "1 x M.2 Socket 3 with vertical M Key design, Type 2242/2260/2280 storage devices support (PCIE mode only)"

Also running BIOS version 4101.

Comment: “They sent me the missing bracket that I either misplaced or never received…” Crazy question… But if they were cool enough to send you the new bracket, maybe you can contact them about your system not being able to see the new device?

Comment: The slot either supports NVMe drives or it doesn't.  The bracket can't NOT support a NVMe M.2 SSD since it's just a bracket.  Which means it's either the motherboard that doesn't support the drive (unlikely since NVMe is NVMe) or something else is going on.  I would contact ASUS for assistance

Comment: @Giacomo1968 it was kind of tedious process, after they confirmed that my warranty had ended, so I was hoping to avoid that, but maybe it's the best call.

Comment: Are you using [BIOS Version 4101](https://www.asus.com/us/Motherboards/X99DELUXE/HelpDesk_BIOS/)?

Comment: @harrymc sorry for the delay, had to check. Yes I am running 4101. Editing question now, thanks!

Comment: contacted customer support, they said if it fits in the slot it will work, so I'm going to try again.